# .htaccess recognize string and replace it

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration

I would like that .htaccess recognize string in my url and replace it with another.
Previously I used SEO components, but today I want to use Joomla native seo, and I have different structure of my url addresses.

I would like to get folder1 replaced with folder3 automatically when browser try to access it.

Example:
www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder4/article-title-1
to
www.domain.com/folder3/folder2/folder4/article-title-1

Any of the folder* doesn't exist on my server and links  are generated by Joomla menu structures with SEO configuration ON.

I've tried to use code below but without success.

```
RewriteRule ^/?folder1([a-z/.]*)$ /folder3$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

htaccess will not give you proper result as this doesn't rewrite `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` so Joomla routing works with bad URI

What will help is creating system plugin and replace this variable in `onAfterInitialise` function

---

if you don't need to save the URL you can use something from here http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess

---

your htaccess rule will be

```
RewriteRule ^folder1(/.*)$ /folder3$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Mmaybe there is different code that can be used. What I have shown above is something that I have used but not sure if it is wrong.

Creating plugin, bit advanced...

Comment: Well, yes maybe I was to deep in it ) it was for more advanced task, if you didn't need to say URL - you may use standard htaccess redirect rule

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: thank you for your update but doesn't say anything about how to find one string and replace it with another.
just for the reminder, these are SEO menu items, not actual folders located on server.

I need htaccess rewrite/redirect rule that will find one word and just replace it with another, like it shown on my post.

Comment: And overall if you want to test your redirect - you can use this service http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: I've added your rule to answer

Comment: this solution works but I have to make all folders physically on my server.
problem here is that I have hundred of articles like "www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder4/article-title-1" under lot of folders/subfolders. To get folder 1 replaced by folder 3 I have to create all folders/subfolders on my server. Not sure if there is option to force htaccess to replace a string with another no matter on what structure we are referring to.

Comment: @stvlada no, you don't need to create those folders, it all can be done by this simple rule. If you have troubles on resolving this issue - fill free to contact JoomPlace Support, say that I you addresses to them - we'll help you with no cost.

Comment: This rule doesn't work if I don't have physical folders on my server. If folder doens't exist website redirects me to the error page on my website. If folders are there, then rule is working.

Will try to get rich of them and I will post solution at the end here as well.

Comment: standard htaccess has rule that rewrites everything that is not existing to index.php. and this rewrite rule set as Final. Did you put your redirect code to proper location?(marked as custom redirects)